# PNG images overlaid but with a link to change each, one at a time - Javascript/jQuery/CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am really struggling with this. I have a small amount of knowledge of coding like this, but more modifying than actual coding.

I am looking for some code to allow me to overlay 2 different layers of PNG images (a door and a door handle) which will then each change to a different image when a link is clicked on the page, e.g. a different handle or a different door style or colour.

```
#png1 {
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
z-index:0;
}

#png2 {
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
z-index:0;
}
```

The above CSS combined with the below HTML gives me the overlay, it would just be nice to get it in a frame (DIV maybe?) and then for a HTML link to then change the image

```
<img id="png1" src="aub.png" />
<img id="png2" src="handle1.png" />
```

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Added the codes in to the original post

Comment: To change an image, do `$("#png1").prop('src', 'mynewimage.png');`

Answer (score 0):

*position:absolute* and *z-index* css property are your tools

door handle must have supperior z-index than door

use jQuery to the behaviour to change it by clicking a link

Answer (score 0):

Add a wrapper div around the images. Set it to position relative. Give the image you want on top a higher z-index than the one you want on the bottom.

Use the jQuery click function to change the src of the image tag or to show/hide other images.

Assuming you create two links with the classes of .my_link_1 and .my_link_2 to act as the triggers for the images you want to change:

```
$(".my_link_1").click(function() {
  $("#png1").attr('src', 'red.png');
});

$(".my_link_2").click(function() {
  $("#png1").attr('src', 'blue.png');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Billy

Sorry to be a pain, but could you explain how I get the .click function to work as a link? I've got the following but how does that work with a link? Sorry, I know this is simply stuff really!

 <script> $("#png1").click('src', 'red.png'); </script>

Comment: I've updated my answer - hope that explains it. Quite a few ways to do this but this one should do the job.